# Finding a control on a Winforms using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I am trying to find an elegant way to get controls on a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form by name. For example:

```
MyForm.GetControl "MyTextBox"

...
```

But this has to make sure it goes through all the controls recursively.

What's the most elegant way to implement this using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ isn't necessarily best-suited to unknown-depth recursion; just use regular code...

```
public static Control FindControl(this Control root, string name) {
    if(root == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
    foreach(Control child in root.Controls) {
        if(child.Name == name) return child;
        Control found = FindControl(child, name);
        if(found != null) return found;
    }
    return null;
}
```

with:

```
Control c = myForm.GetControl("MyTextBox");
```

Or if you don't like the recursion above:

```
public Control FindControl(Control root, string name) {
    if (root == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while (stack.Count > 0) {
        Control item = stack.Pop();
        if (item.Name == name) return item;
        foreach (Control child in item.Controls) {
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In your first example you mean to say return child.

Comment: Your example implementation line should be `Control c = myForm.FindControl("MyTextBox");`, no?

Comment: @Brad quite possibly; since it was over 3 years ago, my memory is hazy

Answer (score 14):

### "Elegant" Control Filter (No LINQ)

Thanks to C# 3 there are many elegant solutions. This one doesn't use LINQ query operators; it uses lambdas and delegates.

This filters all controls for given criteria (can filter against multiple criteria). Returns multiple matches. It allows for more than name detection.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Recurses through all controls, starting at given control,
    /// and returns an array of those matching the given criteria.
    /// </summary>

    public Control[] FilterControls(Control start, Func<Control, bool> isMatch) {
        var matches = new List<Control>();

        Action<Control> filter = null;
        (filter = new Action<Control>(c => {
            if (isMatch(c))
                matches.Add(c);
            foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
                filter(c2);
        }))(start);

        return matches.ToArray();
    }
```

### Filter Usage...

It's quite flexible as far as usage

```
Control[] foundControls = null;

// Find control with Name="tabs1".
foundControls = FilterControls(this,
    c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Equals("tabs1"));

// Find all controls that start with ID="panel*...
foundControls = FilterControls(this,
    c => c.Name != null && c.Name.StartsWith("panel"));

// Find all Tab Pages in this form.
foundControls = FilterControls(this,
    c => c is TabPage);

Console.Write(foundControls.Length); // is an empty array if no matches found.
```

---

### Equivalent Extension Method

Extension methods add an heir of elegancy to applications also.

The exact same logic can be injected into an extension method like so.

```
static public class ControlExtensions {

    static public Control[] FilterControls(this Control start, Func<Control, bool> isMatch) {
        // Put same logic here as seen above (copy & paste)
    }
}
```

Extension **usage** is:

```
// Find control with Name="tabs1" in the Panel.
panel1.FilterControls(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Equals("tabs1"));

// Find all panels in this form
this.FilterControls(c => c is Panel);
```

---

### Another Extension to Return One Control or `null`

Calls the first extension method (see above) to get all matching controls, then returns the first one in the matches, otherwise null if the match list is empty.

This isn't efficient because it iterates over all controls even after finding the first match - but just playing around here for the sake of SO comments.

```
    static public Control FilterControlsOne(this Control start, Func<Control, bool> isMatch) {
        Control[] arrMatches = ControlExtensions.FilterControls(start, isMatch);
        return arrMatches.Length == 0 ? null : arrMatches[0];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks jdk, it's really good. The only thing is I need to get a single result or null. Getting an array is better. So maybe I should use your filter method to write another one that returns a single control or null. This is used in event handling etc, so I need to get a single control and add the event to it.

Comment: Added an extension to return 1 Control or null. I'm not looking for this to be the accepted solution, just having some fun with C# and leaving the results here for perusal.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can create recursive linq queries directly, but you could create a recursive method using linq:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> FlattenHierarchy(this Control c)
{
    return new[] { c }.Concat(c.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(child => child.FlattenHierarchy()));
}
```

This should return a sequence containing every control contained in a control hierarchy. Then finding a match is straightforward:

```
public Control FindInHierarchy(this Control control, string controlName)
{
    return control.FlattenHierarchy().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == controlName);
}
```

Personally I'd avoid using linq in this way though.

Comment: This is probably the best solution - especially given that FlattenHierarchy can be reforumulated into a generic method. Why would you avoid using LINQ in this way?

Comment: @albahari - Yes you're probably right thinking about it - I initially thought it might be quite inefficient but it's probably ok.

Comment: +1 because you did it with LINQ as requested, against your own better judgement

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy...

LINQ isn't very good at recursion <strike>and `Control.Controls` isn't LINQ enabled</strike> (needs Cast).

Sometimes a method is the best solution. Since you can write one that works for all Controls it will be even more reusable than a LINQ query. It could be an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why nobody suggested this.

```
 var control = Controls.Find("MyTextBox",false);
 TextBox searchedTexBox = control[0] as TextBox;
```