# can we access textbox(s) in C# as in VB6 to code all the textbox(s) with index value where all the textbox(s) having the same name?

Tags: c#, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a Control Array in C# 2010.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435293/how-do-i-make-a-control-array-in-c-sharp-2010-net)

i have 10 textbox in my window form can i write a source code in C#  as in VB6 to access all the textbox with index value where all the  textbox having the same name?

Answer (score 4):

VB6 style Control arrays are not supported, but you can easily accomplish this by addiing each one the controls to a seperately-declared array or list.

```
private List<Textbox> txtSameName = new List<Textbox>();
```

in constructor, after InitializeComponent:

```
txtSameName.Add(txtOne);
txtSameName.Add(txtTwo);
txtSameName.Add(txtThree);
txtSameName.Add(txtFour);
```

then you can iterate by index or via foreach:

```
for (int 1 = 0; i < txtSameName.Length; i++)
{
   txtSameName[i].Text = string.empty;
}
```

to wire up a common handler:

```
foreach (Textbox tb in txtSameName)
{
   tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtSameName_TextChanged);
}
```

and then a single handler as follows:

```
private void txtSameName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Textbox tb = sender as Textbox;
   tb.BackColor = Colors.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name is irrelevant really in Winforms. You can just add the textboxes to an array and index them that way.

Answer (score 0):

IF you only need to access the controls I think you could do something like this:

```
public TextBox[] TextBoxesArray
{
    get
    {
        return Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(control => control).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to extend this to allow adding/removing `TextBox`es from the array and update the `Controls` collection at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "built-in" way like in VB6.  However, assuming your text boxes are named `txtBox0`, `txtBox1`, etc., and there are fewer than 10...

If you use the [method shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024801/17635), then you could write something like:

```
var myTextBoxes =
    this.FilterControls(c => c is TextBox)
        .Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.StartsWith("txtBox"))
        .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
        .ToArray();
```

Now `myTextBoxes` should contain your array.