# how can we clear the all form controls on winform?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to clear all controls specially textbox nad combobox.
and I am using the following control to clear all fields.

```
private void ResetFields()
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            else if (ctrl is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox dd = (ComboBox)ctrl;
                if (dd != null)
                {
                    dd.Text = string.Empty;
                    dd.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is not working properly in group box. In group box I have combo box and text box as well. Combo box shows the selected index = 1 of the group box. I also want to clear these controls as well.
Any suggestions ????

Comment: You'll need to do it recursively for all children.

Comment: any type of examples??? how to do it recursively

Comment: have you tried clearing items in combo box.....Up to my understading of this question, I sugest you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024607/finding-a-control-on-a-winforms-using-linq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `TextBox` and `ComboBox`

```
    public static void ClearSpace(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            var textBox = c as TextBox;
            var comboBox = c as ComboBox;

            if (textBox != null)
                (textBox).Clear();

            if (comboBox != null)
                comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

            if (c.HasChildren)
                ClearSpace(c);
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
        ClearSpace(this); //Control
```