# Text from textboxes to list

Tags: c#, string, list, for-loop, textbox

I'm REALLY new to C# and programming overall, so my question might be stupid in your opinion but here it is.

I have created a form which contains 7 textboxes and i want to collect text from these textboxes and add them to a list. I however get an error saying, `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable". What should I do?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (TextBox[i].Text == "")
    {
        days.Add("Restday");
    }
    else
    {
        days.Add(TextBox[i].Text);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the textbox references in an array so that you can easily loop through them. If your textboxes are named `TextBox1` to `TextBox7`:

```
TextBox[] boxes = {
  TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7
};

foreach (TextBox box in boxes) {
  if (box.Text == "") {
    days.Add("Restday");
  } else {
    days.Add(box.Text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

TextBox is a type. so TextBox[i] is causing you trouble.

You can alway do something like this

```
foreach(Control ctrl in yourform.Controls)
{
    Textbox = ctrl as TextBox;
    if(txtBox != null)
    {
        if (txtBox.Text == "")
        {
            days.Add("Restday");
        }
        else
        {
            days.Add(txtBox.Text);
        } 
    }
}
```

This work for a basic form. If you have pannel and other container to organize your controls the approch described in [Guffa answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778515/2145522) might be better. This could also be rewritten as method who accept a collection of `Control` recursive use to reach all controls.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you don't have an array named `TextBox` that is why the error. You can try following:

```
List<strig> days = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>
                                .Select(r=> string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Text) 
                                            ? "Restday" : r.Text)
                                .ToList();
```

But the above would give you the textboxes added on the form directly, If these textboxes are inside other control then [you can look for recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024607/finding-a-control-on-a-winforms-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Go into the form editor and select one of your textboxes. Now find the properties window. If it's not visible then click View->Properties Window

One of the properties in there will be the name of the textbox control. Use that to access it's text value like so:

```
days.Add(txtMyTextboxName.Text);
```

If you *must* iterate through the textboxes you can do this:

```
foreach(var Textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (Textbox.Text == "")
    {
        days.Add("Restday");
    }
    else
    {
        days.Add(Textbox.Text);
    }   
}
```

But bear in mind this is a pretty non-standard approach and not recommended.